# Convert a windows installer to DesktopApp uwp and send to Store

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I'm using Desktop App to convert an application.

Ok it is possible by:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter

But when I try to SUBMIT the .appx to the windows store, the following error appears:

Package acceptance validation error: You don't have permissions to specify the following namespaces in the appx manifest file of the package MyCompany.appx: http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities
Package acceptance validation error: Your developer account doesn’t have permission to submit apps converted with the Desktop Bridge at this time. https://aka.ms/desktopbridgeforwindowsstore

I saw that I should request revision of my developer account to send APPS:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge

I already sent this, but no response is given.

What is necessary to push the APP to Store via DesktopApp Converter?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to convert a Windows installer to a Windows app package (.appx package) for the purpose of Store distribution. That's precisely the purpose of the Desktop Bridge, and we have already converted numerous installers that way and released the apps in the Windows Store. Please clarify the steps you have tried to deploy the converted installer and run the app from that package.

Comment: please take a look at my last edit on stackoverflow.

Comment: Please contact me directly (swick at microsoft.com) so we can dig up your request and figure out why it wasn't processed.